# Material that can block all wavelengths larger than UV light

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

Is there a material out there that can either:

1. Block all wavelengths larger than that of UV light

or

2. Block all wavelengths outside (greater than or less than) the UV light spectrum?

If so, what is the name of the material?

Comment: Are you looking for a UV filter? In other words it lets UV light pass but blocks visible light?

Comment: Expensive filters, sometimes different kinds stacked,

Answer (score 0):

It depends how precisley you need to chose the cut-off wavelength, how far into the visible and IR you need it to block, how well you need it to transmit the UV and how much you need it to block the other wavelengths.

When we specify filters we need to consider all of the factors, the more stringent the requirements the more expensive it gets !

Typically to get the best ratio between the wavelengths transmitted and reflected you use [interference filters](https://www.edmundoptics.com/f/shortpass-filters/12876), often combined with a simple colored glass filter to block the longer wavelengths.

A quick cheap(ish) simple alternative if you can just reflect everything except UV is a very thin gold coating on a UV transmitting substrate like fused silica.